# What is a Projection?

Tags: database, nhibernate, relational-algebra

What is a Projection, in terms of database theory and NHibernate when using SetProjection()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Projection in NHibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746995/what-is-a-projection-in-nhibernate)

Answer (score 52):

Projection is one of the basic operations of Relational Algebra. It takes a relation and a (possibly empty) list of attributes of that relation as input. It outputs a relation containing only the specified list of attributes *with duplicate tuples removed*. In other words the output must also be a relation.

Example, if the relation R{A,B}, contains three tuples {1,10},{2,10},{3,20} then the projection of R over the attribute list {B} would contain 2 tuples: {10},{20}.

In short, projection is more or less equivalent to SELECT DISTINCT in SQL (excluding cases with nulls and duplicate columns).

Answer (score 36):

Very simply, it's a function which takes an input (e.g. a database row) and produces an output (e.g. one of the columns from the row, or perhaps some calculation based on multiple columns).

Comment: In Hibernate, where does the function that produces the output (e.g. the column) get executed? Does it happen on the SQL database server or does it happen on the application/hibernate server after the full row results are returned? Thanks.

Comment: @KyleM: It's too long since I've used NHibernate to say for sure, but I'd expect it to be executed as part of the SQL.

Comment: Thanks.. that's what I think as well. I just remembered another way to check (hibernate query logging, which we usually don't use..), so I'll check and report back.

Comment: @KyleM: The count projection definitely happens in the SQL, if you look at the query that is issued, it is select `count(columnName)`

Answer (score 22):

Projection means subset of columns in a query.

```
select x, y, z from YourTable
```

x, y, z is the projection here.

Comment: Doesn't it mean "subset of columns" rather than "number of columns"?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of hibernate, it's like specifying what columns to select. As opposed to letting the mappings determine what columns are fetched. This means you can specify sql functions, subqueries, a single column, or maybe all of the above via a ProjectionList. For example, if you wanted to count the rows in a table `SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with SQL or database tables:
Projection refers to the number of fields/columns/attributes to return.
Selection deals with number of rows/records to return.
There are good video explanations [here](http://braintem.org/twists/view/131804/)
 and [here](http://braintem.org/twists/view/131805/)

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.