# What is a Projection in NHibernate?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, projection

I have a project where I'm using NHibernate to handle bindings to the database. So far I have mostly been using the basics when it comes to queries. Now I'm struggling with a more difficult query, and I notice new parts of NHibernate. In particular I'm curious about `SetProjection`, which seems to be important when doing queries.

What is a Projection, and how will I typically use it? I am assuming that a projection is a general term when it comes to databases, so you are welcome to give more general answers too..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Projection as Antoine said is transformation. In terms of query it is:

```
SELECT *PROJECTION* FROM Table
```

`*PROJECTION*` is expression for data transformation.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDER
```

The Criteria equivalent would be:

```
List orders = session.createCriteria(Order.class).list();
```

No projection here, we take data without transformation. If we want one:

```
SELECT NAME FROM PRODUCT
```

Here, the Projection class comes into play. The above query can be rewritten into a Criteria query as:

```
List products=session.createCriteria(Product.class)
     .setProjection(Projection.property(\"name\"))
     .list();
```

So we project all rows to single item: `name` field.

There are other projections: `Projection.rowCount()` for example (for `COUNT(*)`)

Comment: Thanks! Clarifying. And yes - I started by googling, but I didn't really find the answer. Btw; downvote wasn't from me. +1

Comment: As for first row of your answer, I got here from first result of google =)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about NHibernate, but in general, a projection is a transformation of a set into another set. In SQL, it is expressed as a SELECT.